# Updating parent table should update values in child table

Tags: mysql

Parent Table :

LevelID LevelName

---

1        Level1 
2        Level2

Child Table:

GroupId GroupName LevelID

---

1        Level1-G1   1  
2        Level1-G2   1  
3        Level2-G3   2  
4        Level2-G4   2

Where LevelId is the primary key for parent table and foreign key for child table.  Is there any way to reflect the change of level names of the parent table in the child table.

For eg:  Updated Level1 to L1 and the child table should look like this.

GroupId GroupName LevelID

---

1        L1-G1       1 
2        L1-G2       1  
3        Level2-G3   2  
4        Level2-G4   2

Is it possible to do with mysql.  Tried on update cascade, but does not seem to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you keeping redundant data anyway? With the level id you could read the level name when selecting the data, and concatenate to the `Gx` part of the group name.

Comment: I agree, but want to know if somehow this can be done..this will simplify lot of my calculations